# external jar with config.xml adding to eclipse project

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to add external JAR file to eclipse android project. JAR package have config.xml and resources/ folder - where to add them? Because I`m getting error:

System.out Error: Could'nt load configuration file ./config.xml
I've tried to copy resources and config.xml to assets/ folder - but it did`nt help.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to ship these files (config.xml, and resources/ folder) with your app, add them to `assets/`, and then access them with AssetManager (getAssetManager() to get one)

**EDIT 1:** Anyways, if it tries to open ./config.xml, try creating one in /data/data/your.app's.package/files (or `getFilesDir()` from Java), or copying the one from the .jar there

Comment: Varga - The external jar is runnable which needs config.xml. I cannot edit the files of the jar.

Comment: Runnable? Chances are it won't work on Android, which cannot run Java .class files or .jar files, because it uses Dalvik, and can only run DEX bytecode. Or is it a library?